# Faux login required for App Store submission reviews?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am about to upload my app today and remember reading something about giving reviewers the ability to login using a faux account, otherwise they will reject the app. However, I am not really sure if this is correct, or if it is, how to go about it? Users can login with their account in my app, but how would I provide the reviewers with login information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a field in the iTunes Connect app submission form that allows you to enter sample credentials. All you have to do is create a dummy account on whatever site your app accesses and provide the login information for that.

Comment: The field is called "Demo Account - Full Access", description says:
"Please provide us with the details of any test accounts that we can use for testing your application. This can include usernames, passwords, access codes, etc."